# Aborting All Ajax Calls - jqXHR

Tags: jquery, ajax, break, jqxhr

Basically im using jqXHR with asmx. I want to do this if its possible;

Overally in everypage im using 6-7 ajax calls with sync or async depends on which method it is. But when one of them got error i want to break that ajax call and after the all of ajax calls.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use an array to store the returned object from each ajax call, and iterate over that array to abort them all:

```
var XHR = []
........//later
var myajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url
}).done(function() {
    //do something
}).fail(function() {
   abortAll();
});
XHR.push(myajax);

function abortAll() {
   XHR.each(function(i,e) {
      e.abort();
   });
}
```

Comment: i got 11 ajax calls this works well on first 8 calls but i got error at 9th and want to cancel the other 2 calls and thats the thing not working any idea? :)

Comment: also checked to length of the array when i got the error at 9th is 8. and the other 2 calls working async. they triggered when the 9th finished or got error.

Comment: [link](http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/920/ajaxsy.jpg) and this is the all of my ajax calls as you can see i got the error and thats what i want but the other 2 just triggered when the 8th finished or got error :(

Answer (score 3):

Every time you create an ajax request it returns an object, you can use it to abort the request:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    success: function(data){}
});
```

and then use the request to abort the call:

```
request.abort();
```

Comment: May as well use an array `var request=[]` then `.push()` requests into it and abort 'em all with a `for` loop or `$.each`.